# How many ACTUAL possibilities from a 3D printer?

Tags: combinatorics

**They say that with 3D printing, there's "limitless" possibilities.**

Well I've always wondered about that. I own a 3D printer with a print bed of $130\text{ mm}\times 130\text{ mm}$ and $130\text{ mm}$ height. Given that the printer can move with a precision of $0.02\text{ mm}$ on the $x$ and $y$ axes and $0.06\text{ mm}$ precision on the $z$-axis, and has a $0.4\text{ mm}$ nozzle, what is the *actual* number of possible plastic combinations that my 3D printer can make?

This is assuming that it can move anywhere in the print volume and place a blob of plastic of at least $0.4\text{ mm}\times0.4\text{ mm}\times 0.06\text{ mm}$ (in reality the blob is a cylinder, but for simplicity you can assume it is a cube). Also, I don't mind if the points in the structure aren't all connected, just floating in air. I want to know the absolute number of possibilities.

Thank you!

Comment: I really like this question, but there are slight assumptions that must be considered beforehand. Can blobs be combined? For example, can I 3D print two $0.04\text{ mm}\times0.04\text{ mm}\times0.06\text{ mm}$ blobs joined at a corner in a $0.02\text{ mm}\times0.02\text{ mm}\times0.06\text{ mm}$ region? If so, can blobs also be combined in the z-direction? (Even though actual 3D printers wait for each layer to dry.)

Comment: @URL Oh! Sorry! I meant to write that the nozzle is 0.4mm, not 0.04. 0.4 x 0.4 is the minimum size, they can be as big as the print volume.

Comment: Can blobs “combine”, though?

Comment: @URL, yes, they can combine in any direction. For example, 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.06 is the minimum blob size, but 0.4 x 0.42 x 0.12 is also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach is to compute the number of voxels in your volume.  In $x$ and $y$ you have $\frac {130}{0.02}=6500$ locations.  In $z$ you have $\frac {130}{0.06}\approx 2166$ locations.  This gives $6500^2\cdot 2166=91513500000$ voxels.  Each can be filled or not, so there are $2^{91513500000}$ possibilities. Please don't try to make them all.

Comment: That doesn’t count every possibility. As @Rafael just explained, it’s possible to create voxels of size not multiples of the basic one.

Comment: I updated the question because I accidentally wrote 0.04 instead of 0.4 (probably doesn't make the math different). More importantly, though, whilst a blob is a minimum size of 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.06, the blob can be placed *anywhere* in the print volume (on a 0.02 mm x & y scale and 0.06 scale for the z). This results in many more combinations.

Comment: Hmm... looking back, I just thought that since the printhead can move anywhere in the XY at a scale of 0.02mm, and anywhere in the Z with 0.06, the voxel size should be described as 130/0.02 * 130/0.02 * 130/0.06. Does that work? You can update your answer.

Comment: That multiplies the number of positions in $X$ and $Y$ by $20$ each, so the number of voxels by $400$.  The $325$ becomes $6500$.  Similarly, the exponent on the $2$ goes up by a factor $400$.  The approach is the same.  It is still a very large finite number.

Comment: Well, if you think it works, you can update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rafael:  Done.  If you understand the earlier answer you should be able to do this